# How to reload swf (reload class definition) in a running application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash

I work with FlashPro and FlashBuilder. I have an application in AIR, which reads resources from SWF created in FlashPro.

The problem is that if I change something in the FlashPro and reload swf'a nothing has changed. I get the same symbols, and functions return the same data.

If I run the application again and load swf only then I can see the changes.

It seems that if AVM2 (FlashPlayer) load a class it is confident that this class does not change its content.

I use class Loader to load swf.

Does anyone know how to reload swf

---

My function:

```
protected function loadResourceFile() :void
{
    if (_resourcesFile != null) {
        _resourcesFile.unload();
        _resourcesFile = null;      
    }

    var ba :ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var fs :FileStream = new FileStream();

    var srcFile : File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(edResourcesSWF.text);
    try {
        fs.open(srcFile, FileMode.READ);  // Otwarcie synchroniczne, można też asynchronicznie - openAsync()
        fs.readBytes(ba);
        fs.close();
    } catch (e :Error) {
        Alert.show('Błąd odczytu z pliku: ' + srcFile.nativePath + '\n\n' + e.message, 'Błąd');
        return;
    }

    _resourcesFile = new Loader();
    _resourcesFile.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadResourceFile_loaded);
    _resourcesFile.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loadResourceFile_ioErrorHandler);
    try {
        var context :LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
        context.allowCodeImport = true;
        context.allowLoadBytesCodeExecution = true;

        _resourcesFile.loadBytes(ba, context);  //  <--- Load SWF
    }
    catch (e :Error) {
        Alert.show('Nie można wczytać pliku zasobów: "' + edResourcesSWF.text + '"\n\n' + e.message, 'Błąd');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is acceptable for the Flash Player/Adobe AIR to assume that compiled assets will not change during runtime.  So, it is acceptable to assume that if your recompile assets you have to reload / restart the app.  Can you share the code you use for loading? Have you tried giving the SWF a different file name before reloading?  How are you loading the SWF at runtime?  How are you 'unloading' the SWF before reloading it?

Comment: Yes I try change name of swf and it didn't help. Probably because class names in swf are the same. I check this in "Flash Decompiler Trillix".; I invoke `Loader.unload()` before I load the file again. Look up...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here... the first is that when you load the same Class from different swfs (which in essence is what you are doing), Flash assumes that the first definition it got is the correct one. You can get around this with things like [loader contexts](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html), but I suspect that your loading swf is directly touching the loaded Classes, so this probably won't work for you. I see you're choosing to load everything in the main context, so it's definitely not going to work for you until you change that.

Instead of directly touching the Classes, instead program to Interfaces (Abstract or Base Classes would work as well) and provide an API for your main swf to request the local implementation of the Interface from the loaded swf. This would allow you to isolate the different Class implementations inside the Application context.

A second issue is probably that the swf is being cached by the browser. You can get around this by appending a parameter to the url: loader.load('http//:www.yourDomain.com/swfs/yourfile.swf?nocache=' + getTimer());